# How to modify a single entry in SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a SelectItem, I get back a collection of objects/values for use in a dropdown list. I need to find a specific item in the returned list and set the Selected property to true if it matches a value (`stateCode`) that is passed in... I have this which, obviously, doesn't work. The line after the `//psuedo` comment is where I'd like to make the change. Any idea on how to do this? I don't seem to have access to the properties I want to change...

```
SelectList retVal = new SelectList(this.db.States.Where(x => x.Col1== someVal), "ValueCol", "TextCol", someVal);
foreach (SelectListItem item in retVal) {
    //psuedo
    retVal[item.Index].Selected = item.Value == stateCode ? true : false;
}
return retVal;
```

As requested, here is how I'm rendering the dropdown that this SelectItem is bound to:

```
    <div class="select" id="StateDropDown">
        <label for="StateProvince">@Resources.Expert.State_or_Province:</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateProvince, Model.StateList)
    </div>
```

Comment: how are you rendering the dropdown?  If you are using the "for" helper your selected attribute will be ignored.  It is set from the model in that case

Comment: I've edited my code to include the code you're requested.

Comment: in this case you need to set StateProvince in your model to the value you want selected.  mvc will handle the selection for you

Comment: I've already verified by breaking, setting the value of StateProvince to something specifically different and it's still not selecting the correct list option item. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that you are setting it to something that is in your list.  If memory serves it toggles off of the value not the name.

Comment: Correct. In this case, the item that is being selected has a value of "51" and I set "32" which is in the list. In case it's important, I broke in the controller and set the value there.

Comment: I would recommend looking at that value on your view and make sure that what you are setting is making it down.  I have used this many times and it has always worked.  My only guess at this point is there is a disconnect with the data

Comment: I just went in with a guy further up the food chain. There was  indeed a problem with the data... nchar instead of nvarchar so that the value assigned to each option was never what was being stored in another table where it was (correctly) nvarchar... .... yeah.... I feel stupid now.

If you wanna suggest posting an answer about taking a look at the data, that'd be the accepted answer.

Comment: Attempting to set the `Selected` property of a `SelectListItem` is pointless when you binding to a property using `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. All you need is `SelectList retVal = new SelectList(this.db.States.Where(x => x.Col1== someVal), "ValueCol", "TextCol"); return retVal;` If the value of property `StateProvince` matches the value of one of the options it will be selected. Thats how model binding works!

Comment: I just added an answer.  Glad that it helped and you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a selected value to the drop down you don't need to set the value in your select list.  all you need to do is set the value on your model when using a for helper.  So for your drop down

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateProvince, Model.StateList)
```

make sure that you set StateProvince to the value that you want to select.  Also make sure that the value of StateProvince Matches a value that is in your SelectList Model.StateList.

Comment: Yup, it was a data issue. Namely the column in the referenced table was not the correct type while it was in all other tables.

Answer (score 0):

It would be appropriate to pass selected value to @Html.DropdownList method.

Assuming stateCode is state you want to be selected.

Like this.

```
<div class="select" id="StateDropDown">
<label for="StateProvince">@Resources.Expert.State_or_Province:</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateProvince, Model.StateList, stateCode)
```